# Recursive binary search returning a stackoverflow error when word doesn't exist

Tags: java, binary-search

I wrote a recursive binary search method, it works if the word exists in the dictionary however, when I enter a word that doesn't exist like "rwetjia" I get a stackoverflow error

```
    public boolean wordCheck(String target, int start, int end) {
    target.toLowerCase();
    if (end >= 1) {
        int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
        int targetside = target.compareTo(words.get(middle));// Finds which side the word is on
        if (targetside == 0) {
            return true;
        } // Word is at the middle (the word exists and has been found)
        else if (targetside > 0) {
            return wordCheck(target, middle + 1, end);
        } // If target word is on the right side of the array, "cuts" the other half off
        else {
            return wordCheck(target, start, middle - 1);
        }
    } // If target word is on the left side of the array, "cuts" the other half off
        return false; // Word is not in the dictionary
}
```

Comment: what do you think happens when you come in the loop that calls this? return wordCheck(target, middle + 1, end); you'll be stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: What is `end`? the index of the last element, or the index of the last element plus one? In other words, to search in the full list, would you call `wordCheck(target, 0, words.size())` or `wordCheck(target, 0, words.size()-1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (end >= start) {
```

instead of

```
if (end >= 1) {
```

UPDATE:

I'm assuming that `end` is the index of the last element to consider (see my comment above); otherwise, the test would be:

```
if (end > start) {
```

and you would need to replace:

```
        return wordCheck(target, start, middle - 1);
```

with:

```
        return wordCheck(target, start, middle);
```

Comment: yes index is the last element to consider

Comment: Also yes your solution worked thank you! I'm fairly certain I had end >= start at some point but ended up with end >= 1 somehow along the way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your ending condition, i.e. "end >= 1".
Assume for example, you enter a word that is smaller than anything you have in your list. In my example now I'm somewhere, where start = 3 and end = 10. This gives you the following iterations:

```
Iteration. Start - End - Middle
1. 3 - 10 - 6.5
2. 6 - 10 - 8
3. 9 - 10 - 9.5
4. 10 - 10 - 10
5. 11 - 10 - 10.5
```

What you would have to do is to check whether "start <= end" I guess. I haven't thought through the example for the case where it is for example smaller but I think it should catch all the cases.